# Convert date time string in dd/mm/yyyy to datetime format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, datetime, date-format

There is an input from CSV file which is in dd/mm/yyyy format.
I have to pass these date values to the stored procedure.
I want to convert this to mm/dd/yyyy format before I bulkcopy it to the database table from the datatable in the c# code.

Should I do this in the code or in the stored procedure which I am sending it to?
Please advise.I have tried all possible combinations.

Comment: Nither c# nor Sql server stores display format for datetime.  
If you are reading the values from the csv into c# and manipulating them before inserting to the database, you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to get an instance of the `DateTime` structure from these strings.

Comment: ok great will try that.. what if these dates are only 2 of the three columns in the csv file.
i.e. there are 3 columns in the csv file: id, startdate, enddate.
I want to be able to accept the values in dd/mm/yyyy and then convert them to mm/dd/yyyy before i pass them on to the stored procedure.

Comment: Convert "dd/mm/yyyy" values to the `DateTime`, as @ZoharPeled said, by using `DateTime.TryParseExact` and pass those `DateTime` values to the stored procedures without formatting them. Unless you did "very very very bad" thing and stores dates as text in database. If that is a case then you can format them by using `datetime.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 2):

You could you use `DateTime.ParseExact`,

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

where `dateString` is the string representation of the date you want to parse.

If your stored procedures expects a DateTime you could use the `parseDate` value. Otherwise, if it expects a string in the format you mentioned, you can pass the following value:

```
parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY")
```

Comment: This looks like it might work.
except i need to do this for just 2 columns in the csv file out of three..
so could you help with that please!

Comment: @roshanaraman You could apply this to as many columns as you want. You will read the rows of the file and for each row for the two out of three columns you would apply this.

Comment: if i am getting the values from the csv file, please write the code as to how i use it for a particular column. for eg. i have id, startdate and enddate as 3 columns in my csv file.
out of which i need to convert the datetime format for startdate and enddate columns.
How do i implement this.

Comment: @roshanaraman,  _please write the code as to how i use it for a particular column..._ - nice try :)

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your value to DateTime in C# and pass this date value to your SQL client or ORM without converting it to a string

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL column type is set to either one of the date value types it is quite impossible to format the date according to your desire, since the database engine does not store the formatted value but the date value itself.

Make sure to parse the DateTime in-code before updating its value in the SQL database.

```
string date = "2000-02-02";
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(date); // Will throw an exception if the date is invalid.
```

There's also the TryParse method available for you. It will make sure the date value you're trying to parse is indeed in the right format.

```
string input = "2000-02-02";
DateTime dateTime;

if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

After the storage you're more than welcome to select your preferred display format for your DateTime variable using one of the given formats (read link below for a full list of available formats).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx